# Constructor based dependency injection in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Excerpt from [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-some-examples):

> The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection as it enables one to implement application components as immutable objects and to ensure that required dependencies are not null.

My question is whether immutability as well as null dependencies are only possible with Constructor based DI & is that not achievable via setter based DI?

Comment: If you forget to call the setter, its corresponding property will remain uninitialized, i.e. null, the compiler won't complain. If you *have* a setter in the first place, you're explicitly allowing modification. What kind of example do you need to illustrate that?

Comment: Invoking a setter mutates the object, so I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your class A expose a setter method for a dependent object of class B, then you can invoke the setter method on an instance-of-A and change the dependency.
If your class A can receive a dependent object of class B only via constructor parameter, then you have components as immutable objects, furthermore autowiring require not null objects by default and then if you pass null object to constructor parameter spring cannot instantiate objects, this ensures required dependencies are not null.